# CSV to JSON Python, Append Group Category to Dictionary

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

I'm going preface what I'm about to say with "I'm a noob using a terrible 'database'". Below is the structure of my current json output from my csv (outline below). Essentially what I'm trying to do is append the "group" in column A (Information Technology) to each "data" dictionary, so have a "group" key : value that would look like "group": "Information Technology". Then everything under line 5 (Consumer Discretionary) would have the "group": "Consumer Discretionary" key, value.

```
{
  "stocks": [
    {
      "data": {
        "portfolio_average_weight": "5.985"
        "portfolio_total_return": "27.948"
      },
      "name": "Google Inc              "
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "portfolio_average_weight": "2.896",
        "portfolio_total_return": "24.292"
      },
      "name": "Mastercard Inc          "
    }]
}

Column A                           Column B         Column C        Column D

Information Technology           [blank cell]     [blank cell]     [blank cell]
[blank cell]                        Google            5.985           27.948
[blank cell]                     Mastercard           2.896           24.292
Consumer Discretionary           [blank cell]     [blank cell]     [blank cell]
[blank cell]                        xxxxxx         xxxxxxxxx          xxxxxxxxx
```

Here's my current code:

```
with open('test.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line in lines:
      elif line[0] == "" and line[1] != "":
        data = test_two_level(line)
        bottom_level = {
        "name": line[2],
        "data": data}

def test_two_level(line):
  data = {
      "portfolio_average_weight":line[3],
      "portfolio_total_return":line[4]}
  return data
```

What I want the final output to look like:

```
{
  "stocks": [
    {
      "data": {
        "portfolio_average_weight": "5.985",
        "portfolio_total_return": "27.948",
        "group": "Information Technology"
      },
      "name": "Google Inc              "
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "portfolio_average_weight": "2.896",
        "portfolio_total_return": "24.292",
        "group": "Information Technology"
      },
      "name": "Mastercard Inc          "
    }]
}
```

Below is the csv:

```
Information Technology,,,
,Google Inc              ,5.985,27.948
,Mastercard Inc          ,2.896,24.292
Consumer Discretionary,,,
```

Comment: Can you add your python code where you are reading the csv to json?

Comment: So, the dictionary already exists and you want to read through the csv file and add a `"group"` key to the entries in the dictionary's `"stocks"` list whose `'name'` value matches what's `Column B` of the csv?

Comment: @martineau I want to add the "group" in Column A, to the "data" dictionary for each stock. So ideally, it'd look what I added to the bottom of my original post

Comment: That's what I was trying to describe. The only problem I see is that the values you show for the "name" key don't exactly match those under "Column B". Could you post the actual lines from the csv file being read into your question?

Comment: @martineau Thanks for you patience. I added the lines of the csv in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to prefer using`csv.DictReader`over`csv.reader`because the code produced is easier to read, plus having each row read into a dictionary also makes the code more uniform — especially when dealing with JSON objects, which themselves are often comprised of one or more dictionaries.

```
import csv, json

with open('csv_to_json_test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvfields = 'group', 'name', 'average_weight', 'total_return'
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=csvfields)
    database = {}
    stocks = database['stocks'] = []  # initialize item to be parsed
    group = None
    for row in reader:
        if row['group']:
            group = row['group']
        else:
            stocks.append(
                {
                    'data': {
                        "portfolio_average_weight": row['average_weight'],
                        "portfolio_total_return": row['total_return']
                    },
                    'name': row['name'].rstrip(),  # strips trailing spaces
                    'group': group,
                }
            )

print 'database =',
print json.dumps(database, indent=4)
```

Output:

```
database = {
    "stocks": [
        {
            "group": "Information Technology",
            "data": {
                "portfolio_average_weight": "5.985",
                "portfolio_total_return": "27.948"
            },
            "name": "Google Inc"
        },
        {
            "group": "Information Technology",
            "data": {
                "portfolio_average_weight": "2.896",
                "portfolio_total_return": "24.292"
            },
            "name": "Mastercard Inc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @martineau! Makes sense the way you did it. Thanks for taking the time and being patient

Comment: One possible improvement you could make to your database structure would be to have `stocks` be a dictionary of lists, rather than a list of dictionaries that have a common key value (group). This would make it match the structure of your csv file more closely.